# Python cp34 & cp27 .whl not installing

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install numpy with pip using local install on a non-networked machine.

Initially used pip download pandas to obtain the .whl files

```
# python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

When i install i get the following error:

```
# pip install numpy-1.15.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
numpy-1.15.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

According to other posts this .whl matches my install.

If i try:

```
pip install numpy-1.15.4-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl 
numpy-1.15.4-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

It still errors.

```
NAME="Scientific Linux"
VERSION="7.5 (Nitrogen)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="scientific centos fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.5"
PRETTY_NAME="Scientific Linux 7.5 (Nitrogen)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:scientificlinux:scientificlinux:7.5:GA"
HOME_URL="http://www.scientificlinux.org//"
BUG_REPORT_URL="mailto:scientific-linux-devel@listserv.fnal.gov"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Scientific Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.5
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Scientific Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.5"
```

This is my OS i'm running. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Does it have to be a local installation? Does `pip` resolve a compatible version online or can you not connect?

Comment: the machine has no external network, i'm copying the .whl files from another machine

Comment: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"` — 32 or 64 bit? `x86_64.whl` is for 64 bit Python.

Comment: @phd I thought that # python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
64

Comment: SOLVED: i needed to update PIP. I was using version 8 when the latest version is 18.1